# Plot only the data points in the x axes

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

It should have a simple answer which I am missing somehow.

I want to plot only the data points in the x axes. The other points makes things more confusing.[image]

Here is my code:

```
figure(6);
grid on;
hold on;

colorVec = hsv(length(crl));

for i = 1:(length(crl)-1)
    plot(dc,pathLoadMatrix(i,:),'Color',colorVec(i,:),'linewidth',2, 'marker','o');

end

legend('Crl 10%', 'Crl 20%', 'Crl 30%', 'Crl 40%', 'Crl 50%');
xlabel('No of DC');
ylabel('Primary Path Load');
hold off;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `set( gca(), 'xtick', [2:6] )`

An answer must be at least 30 characters, so this is filler text.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple!
Thanks !

Comment: To make sure it matches his data point, `set( gca(), 'xtick', dc )` would be more generic (it would adapt to any `x` vector)